# SQL Server select where most columns match

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure that can have 1 to 4 variables passed to it and it must return the rows where the most columns match or if there are no matching records it returns the default ones (which are null).
The sequence needs to be distinct.

Example table with data:

```
Client_Id Project_ID Phase Task Employee Sequence
--------- ---------- ----- ---- -------- --------
NULL      NULL       NULL  NULL Chris    1
NULL      NULL       NULL  NULL Bob      100
500       NULL       NULL  NULL Joe      1
500       2          NULL  NULL Max      1
```

So the results for Client 100, any project, phase or task would simply be the default NULL records of Chris and Bob. For Client 500 the results would be Joe and Bob. For Client 500, Project 2 the result would be Max and Bob.
Right now I am doing this query by checking the task first then joining it with a query by phase and checking that no rows overlap and doing the same for project then client. It seems incredibly inefficient and there has to be a smarter way about this. Any thoughts?

EDIT - Some query examples, I check first for the case where everything matches

```
 insert into #TempTracking
    select  p.employee, p.sequence
        from        invoices i, projects p
        where   i.client_id = p.client_id
        and     i.project_no = p.project_no 
        and     i.phase = p.phase 
        and     i.task = p.task
```

Then I make the queries less and less specific and check that the sequence does not already exist.

```
  insert    into #TempTracking
select  p.employee, p.sequence
    from        invoices i, projects p
    where   (i.client_id = p.client_id or i.client_id is null)
    and     (i.project_no = p.project_no or i.project_no is null)
    and     (i.phase = p.phase or i.phase is null) 
    and     (i.task = p.task or i.task is null)
    and     NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM #TempTracking t WHERE t.sequence = p.sequence )
```

Comment: `For Client 500, Project 2 the result would be Max and Bob.`  Shouldn't it just return Max for this one?

Comment: Abe raises a good point, how is Bob a valid result for Client 500, Project 2 but Chris is not?

Comment: Agreed.  Same goes for this example he gave `For Client 500 the results would be Joe and Bob`.  Shenanigans!!!

Comment: 2005 is the sql server version.
@Abe, @Seph No, the sequence is 100 for Bob and thats the only 100 entry. All the others have sequence 1 which is why they change.

Comment: Unless there's some additional criteria that you haven't told us, anything that selects 'Bob' *will* also select 'Chris'.  Additionally (mostly because of 'Bob'), your stated desired results don't match your stated expected results...

Comment: @Chris, I don't know what sequence has to do with either of the examples I pointed out....  As @X-Zero pointed out, if there is some functionality based on this column you have not told us about it.

Comment: @X-Zero I think the confusion here is that your're assuming the results are exclusive. So if the client_id is available then it only selects that. The all null values should still be selected if there is no entry with a set client_id that has the same sequence.
I hope that clears it up some. The setup is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Abe The sequence is the most important part of the table. The sequence needs to be unique.
'Bob', 100 is picked up regardless in this example I agree, it is all the sequence 1 entries that change depending on client_id/project/etc.
I'm confused as to how I have confused everyone.

Comment: @Chris, So you want to return at most one row for each sequence value thereby making it unique in the returned result set? What happens when there are two rows that match 2 of the 3 columns you're searching for? For Example, what result would you expect if i searched for Project 3? surely it should return Chris-1, Bob-100, and Joe-1 hence the sequence would not be unique in this return case

Comment: @Seph Yes, I want to return only one row for each sequence. If two rows match it should defer to the row where the most columns match which is why I phrased the question title like I did. If you searched for client 500, project 3 with my current query then yes it would return Chris-1, Bob-100 and Joe-1. That's the entire problem I am currently having. In that case it should return Bob-100 and Joe-1 because bob-100 has no other matches and joe-1 at least matches the client id whereas chris-1 matches nothing.

Comment: @Chris the problem is that suddenly you're saying in some cases "nothing" is a match, but other times there is a match, this changes the answer entirely... :)

Comment: @Seph Nothing is a match if there is no other matching column, i never said differently. The goal of this setup is to have global records that are all null then get more and more specific. There can only be one sequence when we get down to the task level and after filtering through these records we should have the people and the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Most of the columns match" is very vague, but I assume you mean that if they search for null, or if the value in the table is null then assume this record could be included.

If you want the most matching row or all rows that match nothing, then you will need to do something like this (it's starting to get very long)

```
DECLARE @Client_Id VARCHAR(MAX) = '500'
DECLARE @Project_ID VARCHAR(MAX) = '2'
DECLARE @Phase VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
DECLARE @Task VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

SELECT Employee, Sequence 
FROM 
  (SELECT Employee, Sequence, 
  (
    CASE WHEN (Client_Id = @Client_Id OR Client_Id IS NULL OR @Client_Id IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN (Project_ID = @Project_ID OR Project_ID IS NULL OR @Project_ID IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN (Phase = @Phase OR Phase IS NULL OR @Phase IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN (Task = @Task OR Task IS NULL OR @Task IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS MatchCount
WHERE MatchCount = 
  (
    SELECT MAX(
      CASE WHEN (Client_Id = @Client_Id OR Client_Id IS NULL OR @Client_Id IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE WHEN (Project_ID = @Project_ID OR Project_ID IS NULL OR @Project_ID IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE WHEN (Phase = @Phase OR Phase IS NULL OR @Phase IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE WHEN (Task = @Task OR Task IS NULL OR @Task IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    )
    FROM myTable
  )
  -- Now prevent for duplicate sequence numbers
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Employee, Sequence 
    FROM 
      (SELECT Employee, Sequence, 
      (
        CASE WHEN (Client_Id = @Client_Id OR Client_Id IS NULL OR @Client_Id IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN (Project_ID = @Project_ID OR Project_ID IS NULL OR @Project_ID IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN (Phase = @Phase OR Phase IS NULL OR @Phase IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN (Task = @Task OR Task IS NULL OR @Task IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS MatchCount
      FROM myTable) mt2
    WHERE mt2.MatchCount = 
      (
        SELECT MAX(
          CASE WHEN (Client_Id = @Client_Id OR Client_Id IS NULL OR @Client_Id IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
          CASE WHEN (Project_ID = @Project_ID OR Project_ID IS NULL OR @Project_ID IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
          CASE WHEN (Phase = @Phase OR Phase IS NULL OR @Phase IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
          CASE WHEN (Task = @Task OR Task IS NULL OR @Task IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        )
        FROM myTable
      )
      AND mt2.Sequence = myTable.Sequence AND mt2.MatchCount > myTable.MatchCount
  )
```

Note: This will return all records in the table when the number of matching fields is zero.

I'm sure they're are ways this could be cleaned up to not be so verbose by inserting all matching rows into a temp table and including the number of columns that match (`MatchCount`), there by reducing the query considerably.

Now, since you want unique Sequences and the highest matching row / rows to be returned the result you're looking for is more like this:

```
DECLARE @Client_Id VARCHAR(MAX) = '500'
DECLARE @Project_ID VARCHAR(MAX) = '3'
DECLARE @Phase VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
DECLARE @Task VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

INSERT INTO #myTempTable SELECT Employee, Sequence,
  (
    CASE WHEN (Client_Id = @Client_Id OR Client_Id IS NULL OR @Client_Id IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN (Project_ID = @Project_ID OR Project_ID IS NULL OR @Project_ID IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN (Phase = @Phase OR Phase IS NULL OR @Phase IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN (Task = @Task OR Task IS NULL OR @Task IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS MatchCount,
   (
    CASE WHEN (Client_Id IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN (Project_ID IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN (Phase IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN (Task IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS NullCount
--   ,(
--    CASE WHEN (Client_Id = @Client_Id OR @Client_Id IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
--    CASE WHEN (Project_ID = @Project_ID OR @Project_ID IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
--    CASE WHEN (Phase = @Phase OR @Phase IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
--    CASE WHEN (Task = @Task OR @Task IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
--  ) AS MatchCountWithoutNulls

SELECT Employee, Sequence
FROM #myTempTable mtt
WHERE MatchCount = (
    SELECT MAX(MatchCount) 
    FROM #myTempTable mtt2 
    WHERE mtt2.Sequence = mtt.Sequence
  )
  AND NullCount = (
    SELECT MIN(NullCount) 
    FROM #myTempTable mtt2 
    WHERE mtt2.Sequence = mtt.Sequence
  )
```

Or something very close to that, I don't have a test table made up atm so I can't kick it around and see.

Comment: It is vague and I do apologize. I know what the solution should look like but have difficulty articulating the specific problem.

Comment: It's ok, I think I understand what you're trying to articulate... see my latest edit and that should be what you're looking for